# WCF peer-to-peer chat application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I just started to learn WCF. I found an interesting tutorial how to write peer-to-peer chat.

[How to create a peer-to-peer chat application using WPF and wcf in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/theothersteve/archive/2010/04/19/how-to-create-a-peer-to-peer-chat-application-using-wpf-and-wcf-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx#comments)

I did everything as shown in this tutorial and I got exception.

> Blockquote XamlParseException was unhandled. 'The invocation of the
>   constructor on type 'ChatGUI.MainWindow' that matches the specified
>   binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line
>   position '9'.

The problem is in this line.

```
_backend = new ChatBackend.ChatBackend(this.DisplayMessage);
```

I handle this exception

```
            try{
                _backend = new ChatBackend.ChatBackend(this.DisplayMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

and get the following message.

> Message = "Could not find endpoint element with name 'ChatEndpoint'
>   and contract 'ChatBackend.IChatBackend' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element.

Please advise how to fix this situation.

This is my App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netPeerTcpBinding>
                <binding name="Wimpy">
                    <resolver mode="Pnrp" />
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netPeerTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.p2p://Chat" binding="netPeerTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="Wimpy" contract="ChatBackend.IChatBackend"
                name=" ChatEndpoint" kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
                <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost" />
                    <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
        <services>
            <service name="ChatBackend.ChatBackend">
                <endpoint address="net.p2p://Chat" binding="netPeerTcpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="Wimpy" name="Chat" contract="ChatBackend.IChatBackend" />
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you define your Address, Binding, and Contract in your web.config file?

Comment: This can also happen if you never copied the config from a referenced assembly to App.config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I edit my question and add App.config there.

Comment: There is a space in a endpoint name: name=" ChatEndpoint".